# How do you Program Text To Fade in Unity (Using c#)?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, 2d, recipe

I am completely new to c# and Unity, so please don't close my question.

I am following a "recipie" to make text fade from a book called **Unity 5.x Cookbook**. I am pretty sure that I wrote all the code down correctly, but when I try to run my code, the Unity console says this-

> Assets/Scripts/fadeScript.cs(10,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `CountdownTimer' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

I am new to this, so I don't understand what the problem is. Here is my code-

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class fadeScript : MonoBehaviour {

// Al Variables
private CountdownTimer countdownTimer;
private Text fadeText;
private int fadeDuration = 5;
private bool fading = false;

void Start () {

    fadeText = GetComponent<Text>();
    countdownTimer = GetComponent<CountdownTimer>();
    StartFading(fadeDuration);

}

void Update () {
    if (fading) {

        float alphaRemaining = countdownTimer.GetProportionTimeRemaining();
        print (alphaRemaining);
        Color c = textUI.material.color;
        c.a = alphaRemaining;
        fadeText.material.color = c;

        if (alphaRemaining < 0.01) {

            fading = false;

        }

    }
}

    public void StartFading (int timerTotal) {

        countdownTimer.ResetTimer(timerTotal);
        fading = true;

    }

}
```

**What is wrong with my code? What should I do to fix it?** Thanks in advance!

-George

**PS-** I made sure that the script is connected to the actual text, and that the text is named properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script doesn't know what a "CountdownTimer" is. Apparently there's no script named "CountdownTimer" in your project. It appears you forgot to add it from your recipe. That script appears to have two functions in it named `GetProportionTimeRemaining` and `ResetTimer`.

PS: Next time copy the error `The type or namespace name could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?` into google and you'll get the information you need.

Comment: I just realized that the recipe told me to include a script with that name! Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: no problem, also since you're new: it's frowned upon to add "thanks" in the comments since it can get cluttered when many users add this.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help